# switch from brotly-sys to Dropbox brotli

Tags: rust, compression, dropbox, brotli

I used [Brotly-sys](https://github.com/bitemyapp/brotli2-rs) but it seems unmaintened.
So I use [Brotli](https://github.com/dropbox/rust-brotli).
I do an interface to compress and decompress (I use lzma and zstd too):

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

pub use brotli::writer::DecompressorWriter;
pub use brotli::enc::writer::CompressorWriter;

use super::Coder;

impl<W: Write> Coder<W> for DecompressorWriter<W> {
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut W {
        DecompressorWriter::get_mut(self)
    }

    fn finish(self) -> std::io::Result<W> {
        DecompressorWriter::flush(&mut self).map_err(|_| {
            io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "brotli decoder failed to finalize stream")
        });
    }

    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.finish()
    }
}

impl<W: Write> Coder<W> for CompressorWriter<W> {
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> &mut W {
        CompressorWriter::get_mut(self)
    }

    fn finish(self) -> std::io::Result<W> {
        self.flush()?;
        CompressorWriter::flush(&mut self).map_err(|_| {
            io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "brotli encoder failed to finalize stream")
        })
    }

    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.finish()
    }
}
```

But get

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> lib/src/codecs/brotli.rs:13:24
   |
13 |     fn finish(self) -> std::io::Result<W> {
   |        ------          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found `()`
   |        |
   |        implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression
   |
   = note:   expected enum `std::result::Result<W, std::io::Error>`
           found unit type `()`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> lib/src/codecs/brotli.rs:31:9
   |
24 |   impl<W: Write> Coder<W> for CompressorWriter<W> {
   |        - this type parameter
...
29 |       fn finish(self) -> std::io::Result<W> {
   |                          ------------------ expected `std::result::Result<W, std::io::Error>` because of return type
30 |           self.flush()?;
31 | /         CompressorWriter::flush(&mut self).map_err(|_| {
32 | |             io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "brotli encoder failed to finalize stream")
33 | |         })
   | |__________^ expected type parameter `W`, found `()`
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::result::Result<W, _>`
              found enum `std::result::Result<(), _>`
```

But `flush` function doesn't implement `Write` trait.

`Coder` interface is here: https://github.com/Ludea/speedupdate-rs/blob/master/lib/src/codecs/mod.rs#L21

So how can I fix my issue ?
(I can provide GH repo with this issue)
I get this issue on MacOS / Win64 / Linux x86_64.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the source for `Coder`, or a simple mock for it.

Comment: I update my post to provide Coder source

Comment: `CompressorWriter`, is it stands right now, is not compatible with your `Coder` interface, because it doesn't hold an internal buffer. What's your goal with the `Coder` interface? The biggest problem of the `Coder` interface ist that the return type of `finish` is `W`, while the return type of `get_mut` is also `W`, which is incompatible with `CompressorWriter`. Unless I misunderstand something.

Comment: Would you mind posting an example how you would use the `Coder` interface later? I don't 100% get the way it is meant to be used.

Comment: Please don't post links to code, it's against Stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: Yah, I think your `Coder` interface is flawed. You might have to modify it.

Comment: You have an extra `;` after `map_err` in `DecompressionWriter`s impl

Comment: I have to delete `Write` trait into `get_mut` ?

Comment: ```pub trait Coder<W>: io::Write {
    /// Acquires a mutable reference to the underlying writer
    ///
    /// Note that mutation of the writer may result in surprising results if
    /// this decoder is continued to be used.
    fn get_mut(&mut self) ;

    fn finish(self) -> io::Result<W>;

    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W>;
}```

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include information like this :) Multi-line code doesn't format well in comments

Comment: Quote from your repo: *"Note that mutation of the writer may result in surprising results if this decoder is continued to be used."* - Note that this is impossible to happen, the borrow checker will prevent this. That's its whole point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Coder` trait is not compatible with the `CompressorWriter` struct. You might have to modify the `Coder` trait.

I assume the flow of `Coder` is:

- Create compression algorithm that implements `Coder`.
- Get the mutable `Write` object by calling `get_mut()`.
- Write to that object.
- Call `finish()` and retrieve the compressed data from its return value.

Your trait forces the return value of `get_mut()` to be identical to the return value of `finish()`, which isn't the case for `CompressorWriter`.

You don't need to introduce a new generic for this, though; you can simply return `&mut dyn Write` from your `get_mut()` function. This might require some minor tweaks with your other implementations of `Coder`, but should work.

Minor side note: I renamed `get_mut()` to `get_input_writer()`, because it was clashing with `CompressorWriter::get_mut()`, making dealing with it much more annoying.

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

pub use brotli::enc::writer::CompressorWriter;
pub use brotli::writer::DecompressorWriter;

trait Coder<W> {
    fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write;
    fn finish(self) -> io::Result<W>;
    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W>;
}

impl<W: Write> Coder<W> for CompressorWriter<W> {
    fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
        self
    }

    fn finish(mut self) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.flush().map_err(|_| {
            io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::Other,
                "brotli encoder failed to finalize stream",
            )
        })?;
        Ok(self.into_inner())
    }

    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.finish()
    }
}

impl<W: Write> Coder<W> for DecompressorWriter<W> {
    fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
        self
    }

    fn finish(mut self) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.flush().map_err(|_| {
            io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::Other,
                "brotli decoder failed to finalize stream",
            )
        })?;
        self.into_inner().map_err(|_| {
            io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::Other,
                "brotli decoder failed to finalize stream",
            )
        })
    }

    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.finish()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Encode
    let mut coder: Box<dyn Coder<_>> = Box::new(CompressorWriter::with_params(
        Vec::new(),
        1024,
        &Default::default(),
    ));

    coder.get_input_writer().write_all(b"Hello world!").unwrap();
    let output = coder.finish_boxed().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", output);

    // Decode
    let mut decoder: Box<dyn Coder<_>> = Box::new(DecompressorWriter::new(Vec::new(), 1024));

    decoder.get_input_writer().write_all(&output).unwrap();
    let output = decoder.finish_boxed().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output));
}
```

```
[139, 5, 128, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, 3]
"Hello world!"
```

---

While you are on it, I'd also change some other things, for convenience:

- Make the generic of the trait an associated type. It's best practice to avoid generics if they aren't configurable by the user.
- Add `into_boxed_coder` function for convenience.

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

pub use brotli::enc::writer::CompressorWriter;
pub use brotli::writer::DecompressorWriter;

trait Coder {
    type Out;

    fn into_boxed_coder(self) -> Box<dyn Coder<Out = Self::Out>>
    where
        Self: Sized + 'static,
    {
        Box::new(self)
    }

    fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write;
    fn finish(self) -> io::Result<Self::Out>;
    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<Self::Out>;
}

impl<W: Write> Coder for CompressorWriter<W> {
    type Out = W;

    fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
        self
    }

    fn finish(mut self) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.flush().map_err(|_| {
            io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::Other,
                "brotli encoder failed to finalize stream",
            )
        })?;
        Ok(self.into_inner())
    }

    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.finish()
    }
}

impl<W: Write> Coder for DecompressorWriter<W> {
    type Out = W;

    fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
        self
    }

    fn finish(mut self) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.flush().map_err(|_| {
            io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::Other,
                "brotli decoder failed to finalize stream",
            )
        })?;
        self.into_inner().map_err(|_| {
            io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::Other,
                "brotli decoder failed to finalize stream",
            )
        })
    }

    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.finish()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Encode
    let mut coder =
        CompressorWriter::with_params(Vec::new(), 1024, &Default::default()).into_boxed_coder();

    coder.get_input_writer().write_all(b"Hello world!").unwrap();
    let output = coder.finish_boxed().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", output);

    // Decode
    let mut decoder = DecompressorWriter::new(Vec::new(), 1024).into_boxed_coder();

    decoder.get_input_writer().write_all(&output).unwrap();
    let output = decoder.finish_boxed().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output));
}
```

```
[139, 5, 128, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, 3]
"Hello world!"
```

---

Here is a more complete example with implementations for `brotli`, `zstd` and `lzma`:

```rust
use std::{
    io::{self, Write},
    ops::Deref,
};

trait Coder {
    type Out;

    fn into_boxed_coder(self) -> Box<dyn Coder<Out = Self::Out>>
    where
        Self: Sized + 'static,
    {
        Box::new(self)
    }

    fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write;
    fn finish(self) -> io::Result<Self::Out>;
    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<Self::Out>;
}

mod zstd {
    use std::io::{self, Write};
    use zstd::stream::{write::Decoder, write::Encoder};

    impl<W: Write> super::Coder for Encoder<'static, W> {
        type Out = W;

        fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
            self
        }

        fn finish(self) -> io::Result<W> {
            self.finish()
        }

        fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
            self.finish()
        }
    }

    impl<W: Write> super::Coder for Decoder<'static, W> {
        type Out = W;

        fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
            self
        }

        fn finish(mut self) -> io::Result<W> {
            self.flush()?;
            Ok(self.into_inner())
        }

        fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
            self.finish()
        }
    }
}

mod brotli {
    use std::io::{self, Write};

    pub use brotli::enc::writer::CompressorWriter;
    pub use brotli::writer::DecompressorWriter;

    impl<W: Write> super::Coder for CompressorWriter<W> {
        type Out = W;

        fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
            self
        }

        fn finish(mut self) -> io::Result<W> {
            self.flush().map_err(|_| {
                io::Error::new(
                    io::ErrorKind::Other,
                    "brotli encoder failed to finalize stream",
                )
            })?;
            Ok(self.into_inner())
        }

        fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
            self.finish()
        }
    }

    impl<W: Write> super::Coder for DecompressorWriter<W> {
        type Out = W;

        fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
            self
        }

        fn finish(mut self) -> io::Result<W> {
            self.flush().map_err(|_| {
                io::Error::new(
                    io::ErrorKind::Other,
                    "brotli decoder failed to finalize stream",
                )
            })?;
            self.into_inner().map_err(|_| {
                io::Error::new(
                    io::ErrorKind::Other,
                    "brotli decoder failed to finalize stream",
                )
            })
        }

        fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
            self.finish()
        }
    }
}

mod lzma {
    use std::io::{self, Write};

    pub use xz2::write::{XzDecoder, XzEncoder};

    impl<W: Write> super::Coder for XzEncoder<W> {
        type Out = W;

        fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
            self
        }

        fn finish(self) -> io::Result<W> {
            XzEncoder::finish(self)
        }

        fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
            self.finish()
        }
    }

    impl<W: Write> super::Coder for XzDecoder<W> {
        type Out = W;

        fn get_input_writer(&mut self) -> &mut dyn Write {
            self
        }

        fn finish(mut self) -> io::Result<W> {
            XzDecoder::finish(&mut self)
        }

        fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
            self.finish()
        }
    }
}

fn run_example<OutEncode, OutDecode>(
    mut encoder: Box<dyn Coder<Out = OutEncode>>,
    mut decoder: Box<dyn Coder<Out = OutDecode>>,
) where
    OutEncode: Write + std::fmt::Debug + Deref<Target = [u8]>,
    OutDecode: Write + Deref<Target = [u8]>,
{
    // Encode
    encoder
        .get_input_writer()
        .write_all(b"Hello world!")
        .unwrap();
    let output = encoder.finish_boxed().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", output);

    // Decode
    decoder.get_input_writer().write_all(&output).unwrap();
    let output = decoder.finish_boxed().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output));
}

fn main() {
    println!("zstd:");
    run_example(
        ::zstd::stream::write::Encoder::new(Vec::new(), 0)
            .unwrap()
            .into_boxed_coder(),
        ::zstd::stream::write::Decoder::new(Vec::new())
            .unwrap()
            .into_boxed_coder(),
    );
    println!();

    println!("brotli:");
    run_example(
        ::brotli::enc::writer::CompressorWriter::with_params(Vec::new(), 1024, &Default::default())
            .into_boxed_coder(),
        ::brotli::writer::DecompressorWriter::new(Vec::new(), 1024).into_boxed_coder(),
    );
    println!();

    println!("lzma:");
    run_example(
        ::xz2::write::XzEncoder::new(Vec::new(), 5).into_boxed_coder(),
        ::xz2::write::XzDecoder::new(Vec::new()).into_boxed_coder(),
    );
    println!();
}
```

```
zstd:
[40, 181, 47, 253, 0, 88, 97, 0, 0, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]
"Hello world!"

brotli:
[139, 5, 128, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, 3]
"Hello world!"

lzma:
[253, 55, 122, 88, 90, 0, 0, 4, 230, 214, 180, 70, 2, 0, 33, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0, 116, 47, 229, 163, 1, 0, 11, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33, 0, 10, 99, 214, 243, 246, 128, 91, 211, 0, 1, 36, 12, 166, 24, 216, 216, 31, 182, 243, 125, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 89, 90]
"Hello world!"
```

Comment: you change `Write` trait to `&mut dyn Write` But I do the same thing with zstd.

Comment: ```impl<W: Write> super::Coder<W> for Decoder<'static, W> {
    fn get_mut(&mut self) ->  &mut dyn Write {
        Decoder::get_mut(self)
    }

    fn finish(self) -> std::io::Result<W> {
        Ok(Decoder::into_inner(self))
    }

    fn finish_boxed(self: Box<Self>) -> io::Result<W> {
        self.finish()
    }
}```

Comment: get `expected trait object dyn std::io::Write, found parameter type W`

Comment: The way you implement your `Coder for Decoder`, there won't be any Decoding done. You directly write into its output buffer and then return the entire output buffer. You basically bypass the entire encoder. You need to write into the decoder directly. `Decoder::get_mut` is a pointless function for your purpose. Don't just trial and error until an API does something, actually understand the APIs you are using.

Comment: @Vana Added an example that includes implementations for `lzma`, `brotli` and `zstd`. Note that the `zstd` implementation in your repository doesn't actually do anything, it performs zero compression and simply returns the input. I rewrote it so it actually does something. Also, your `lzma` implementation was a lot more complicated than it needed to be; the `xz2` crate also offers a writer based API. I added that as well.

Comment: Works as expected. Now I have to refactor main fn to compress and decompress

Comment: I get ```^^^^^^ method not found in `Box<dyn codecs::Coder<CheckWriter<W, C>>>`
    | ``` when using ```pub fn output_checks(&mut self) -> &mut C {
        &mut self.writer.writer.get_mut().check
    }```. I have to use `get_input_writer ` ?

Comment: (I update the GH repo)

Comment: Well, if you also changed `get_mut()` to `get_input_writer()`, then yes, you have to also change that where you call it.

Comment: Also, please don't paste multi-line code in comments, it doesn't format well.

Comment: I get `no field check on type &mut dyn std::io::Write` if I use `get_input_writer `

Comment: @Vana might be relevant: https://github.com/Speedy37/speedupdate-rs/issues/8

Comment: Seems the original author will not use `Coder::get_input_writer() ` :s

Comment: Also get `the trait `codecs::Coder<_>` is not implemented for `CompressorWriter<W>`  on `return Ok(BoxCoderDirect::boxed(brotli::CompressorWriter::new(output, 4096, quality, lgwin)));`

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant to be a chat site, it's meant for a single question and answer. If you have a new question, please create a new question. According to the author of your crate, we aren't even using `Coder` correctly. So I'm not sure if this discussion leads anywhere.

Comment: Ok, will revert all changes and restart from original crate.

Comment: I sucessfully switch to Dropbox Brotli ;)